# Where to store CSRF tokens? Memcached?

Tags: java, session, memcached, cluster-computing

I run a clustered application and I've been storing CSRF tokens in the user session but I'm having some problems. When several simultaneous requests are received for the same user (same session id) they overlap and I lose some tokens.

Here's what happens:

1. R1 hits the backend & retrieves session from memcached
2. R2 hits the backend & retrieves session from memcached
3. Both R1 & R2 have zero tokens in their copy of the session
4. R1 adds a valid token and updates memcached.
5. R2 adds a valid token and overwrites changes made by R1 in step 4.

When user submits page delivered in R1 it fails because the token is not valid, and has to reload and resubmit.

I'm already using memcached in production, I thought of storing CSRF tokens in memcached but I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

I run 3 backends with a JVM stack.